# Can't use some new created Google SpreadSheets Add-Ons

Tags: google-chrome, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have created two Google SpreadSheet Add-Ons which is adding new options in the Add-On menu.

[Developer Dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1LamZ.png)

From the above print-screen we can see that both Add-Ons have been published, but when I want to use them from a Google SpreadSheet, I don't get the options developed by me, but only the "Help" option:

[HeloWorld Application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfnIF.png)

The code of this Add-On is pretty simple, as currently I am trying to understand and learn how Google Add-ons work:

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createAddonMenu().addItem('HelloWorld', 'HelloWorld').addToUi();
 }

function HelloWorld()
{
  Browser.msgBox('Hello world!!');
}
```

Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: Did you add HelloWorld to the menu for the addon?

Answer (score 0):

The option appeared in the Add-On menu, after a few minutes. 
This issue could be closed.